# Create a movie out of 3d waterfall plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, video, mp4, figure

The following code creates a 3D waterfall plot.

Here are the functions I have defined:

```
### Create waterfall plot ###

def waterfall_plot(fig,ax,X,Y,Z,zlog):
    '''
    Make a waterfall plot
   
    '''
    # Set normalization to the same values for all plots
    zz = np.array(Z).reshape(np.size(Z),1)[:]
    zz =zz[zz>-1e10]
    zz =zz[zz<1e10]
    norm = plt.Normalize(min(zz), max(zz))
    # Check sizes to loop always over the smallest dimension
    n,m = Z.shape
    if n>m:
        X=X.T; Y=Y.T; Z=Z.T
        m,n = n,m

    for j in range(n):
        # reshape the X,Z into pairs 
        points = np.array([X[j,:], Z[j,:]]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)   
        if zlog ==1:
            lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap='plasma', norm=LogNorm())
        else:
             lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap='plasma', norm=norm)
        # Set the values used for colormapping
        lc.set_array((Z[j,1:]+Z[j,:-1])/2)
        lc.set_linewidth(2) # set linewidth a little larger to see properly the colormap variation
        line = ax.add_collection3d(lc,zs=(Y[j,1:]+Y[j,:-1])/2, zdir='y') # add line to axes

    fig.colorbar(lc) # add colorbar
    return line
    


### Create 3D sequantial plot ###    
    
def threeD_plot(choose_column,resolution,t_steps,zmax1,zmax,zlog,save_3D_movie,elev=30., azim=150):
    ### Selected quantity ###
    quantity = choose_column
    col     = ['Density', '$V_{x}$', '$V_{y}$', '$V_{z}$','$B_{x}$', '$B_{y}$','$B_{z}$','$Temperature$']
    
    ### Create mesh ###
    dx    = 1
    x     = np.arange(0,resolution,dx)       # Resolution of grid
    ys    = np.arange(0,t_steps,dx)          # Number of timesteps
    new_z = np.zeros((t_steps,resolution))   # Selected quantity as a function of x,t
    

    ###  Plot figure ###
    
    fig = plt.figure( figsize=(15,10))
    
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    for i in range(0,int(len(choose_file)/resolution)):
        zs = choose_column[i*resolution:resolution*(i+1)]#.values
        if zmax1==1:
            zs[zs>zmax] =1
            zs[zs==0] =1
            new_z[i] = zs
        else:
            new_z[i] = zs
            
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,ys)  # Create X, Y mesh
        
    ### Create waterfall plot ###
    
    waterfall_plot(fig,ax,X,Y,new_z, zlog) 
        
    ### Axes properties ###
    
    ax.set_xlabel('X') ; ax.set_xlim3d(0,resolution); ax.set_xlabel('X point')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y') ; ax.set_ylim3d(0,t_steps) ; ax.set_ylabel('Timestep')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z') ; ax.set_zlim3d(min(choose_column)-0.05,max(choose_column)+0.05); ax.set_zlabel(col[quant])
    ax.view_init(elev=elev, azim=azim)
    
    fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.98)
    if save_3D_movie:
      ### Save 3D images ###
        for ii in range(0,360,40):
            ax.view_init(elev=20., azim=ii)
            fig.savefig(save_folder% ii, format='jpg',dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight')
    else:
            fig.savefig(save_folder, format='jpg',dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight')




# Plot figure 


choose_column =  np.random.uniform(low=0.8, high=1.33, size=(116849,))
                               
resolution    = 1024                                       # Specify resolution of grid in MHD simulation

t_steps       = int(len(specs23)/resolution)               # Specify number of timesteps in MHD simulation

zmax1 = 1                         # Maximum or not
zmax  = 2                         # Maximum allowed value of selected quantity
zlog  = 1                         # Log z axis =1

save_3D_movie = False


threeD_plot(choose_column,resolution,t_steps,zmax1,zmax,zlog,save_3D_movie,elev=30., azim=150)
```

The figure I am getting looks like this:
[image]

I would like to plot each of the lines shown at a time. And then create a movie out of the plots that occur.
I would like to plot each of the lines shown at a time. And then create a movie out of the plots that occur.

Comment: could you please give us some short example dataframe in the code such that we don't need to go to that external link?

Comment: @NicoAlbers I have modified the script so you don't have to read the file. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: currently I can't just copy-paste the script to execute on my machine and adjust. This is what I'd expect, commonly known here as a "minimum reproducing example". It would be great if you could adjusted the question such that it is reproducible without downloading any files - as far as I see the latest edit didn't changed that fact.

Comment: @NicoAlbers Made suggested changes! Copied and pasted on my machine as it is and seems to work fine! Thanks for the suggestions and the help! If you could provide some insight on how I could make this work it would be really helpful!